# Strange POSIX semaphore behavior (stuck on sem_wait on Linux)

Tags: linux, posix, semaphore

I'm trying to solve a school problem envolving POSIX semaphores. I've run into an issue that I've narrowed down to this simplified code:

```
sem_t sem;

void parent() {
    printf("waiting...\n");
    sem_wait(&sem);
    printf("done!\n");
}

void child() {
    sem_post(&sem);
    printf("go!\n");
    exit(0);
}

int main() {
    sem_init(&sem, 1, 0);

    if(!fork())
        child();

    parent();

    sem_destroy(&sem);

    exit(0);
}
```

When compiling (using `gcc -Wall -pthread sems.c -o sems`) and running this program in Linux, I get the following output (the program doesn't finish execution):

```
waiting... 
go!
```

Because I call `sem_post(&sem)` in the child process, I would expect the parent process to move past the `sem_wait(&sem)` and the output to be:

```
waiting...
go!
done!
```

Even more bizarre, out of curiosity, I tried testing it on Windows using CLion (Cygwin compiler), and the program worked as intended. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [man page of `sem_init()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_init.3.html):

> If pshared is nonzero, then the semaphore is shared between processes, and should be located in a region of shared memory (see shm_open(3), mmap(2), and shmget(2)).  (Since a child created by fork(2) inherits its parent's memory mappings, it can also access the semaphore.)

Your `sem` variable is not allocated in shared memory; therefore it can not be shared between processes despite a non-zero `pshared` argument. Each process has its own unique instance of the semaphore.

Comment: @cabralpinto Cygwin does all sorts of funky things to try to work around Windows' lack of equivalents to things like `fork()`. Not surprising at all that it behaves differently than a real Linux or Unix environment.

Comment: In this case it looks like the posix semaphore api is a thin wrapper on top of native Win32 semaphores, which have subtly different semantics for some things.